# Magento 2 - Move Category Page Toolbar/Sorting Options Above Both Columns

Tags: magento2, category, layout, xml, toolbar

What I'm trying to do is move the toolbar/sorting options on the category page above the left column and right column so it spans the full width of my content area.  I'm trying everything and nothing seems to work.  The page layout for my category page is using 2columns-left.  Here is my current markup:

```
<div class="columns>
    <div class="c-sidebar c-sidebar--categories">...</div>
    <div class="column main">...</div>
</div>
```

Inside of `<div class="column main">` is the toolbar I'm trying to move, `<div class="toolbar toolbar-products">...</div>`

What I would like the markup to look like is:

```
<div class="columns>
    <div class="toolbar toolbar-products">...</div>
    <div class="c-sidebar c-sidebar--categories">...</div>
    <div class="column main">...</div>
</div>
```

So far in my `catalog_category_view.xml` I'm trying:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="columns" before="div.sidebar.main" />
    </body>
</page>
```

And I'm also trying to completely remove the toolbar from the layout, but nothing is working.  It leads me to believe that `product_list_toolbar` isn't the correct handle to use to target the toolbar.  I've been struggling with this on and off for the past couple months and would definitely appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Please check blow link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225471/magento2-how-to-move-toolbar