# Magento2 How to move toolbar

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, toolbar, theme-overriding

Anyone have any idea about How to move toolbar before left and right sidebar in magento2 using XML?

Currently it is showing in Right side-bar.

Comment: Have you tried the setTemplate action when referencing the root container will allow you to switch templates to 1column, 2columns-left, 2columns-right or 3columns?

Comment: I have tried to         <move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="columns" before="div.sidebar.main" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

**1.** Create **catalog_category_view** file under

> **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/layout**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list2" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list2.phtml">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers2" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar2" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                <!--
                    <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">8</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">list</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">6</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">9</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label">
                    <argument name="mode" xsi:type="string">grid</argument>
                    <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">all</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">All</argument>
                </action>
                -->
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <!--<argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>-->
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

**2.** Create **list2.phtml** file under

> **vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<!--<div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>-->
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<?php
if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
    $viewMode = 'grid';
    $image = 'category_page_grid';
    $showDescription = false;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
} else {
    $viewMode = 'list';
    $image = 'category_page_list';
    $showDescription = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
}
/**
 * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
 */
$pos = $block->getPositioned();
?>
<!-- <div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
<?php $iterator = 1; ?>
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
<?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
    <?php
    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
    if ($pos != null) {
        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
    }
    ?>
    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
    <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
    <?php
    $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
    ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
    <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
    <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                            <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                <button type="submit"
                                                        title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
        <?php else: ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()): ?>
                                            <a href="#"
                                               class="action towishlist"
                                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                               data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                               role="button">
                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                            </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
    ?>
                                    <a href="#"
                                       class="action tocompare"
                                       title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                       role="button">
                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <?php if ($showDescription): ?>
                                    <div class="product description product-item-description">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                           class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                                    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>-->
```

**Note : Here, i moved toolbar to sidebar(layered navigation).**

I hope it works!

Comment: I don't want to edit any phtml files

Comment: I didn't edited core Magento file, i override .phtml file in theme folder.

Comment: vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/templates/product

See the comment's above the code.

Comment: Please check this link for more information https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-How-to-place-the-sort-option-in-the-left-layered/td-p/37785

Comment: I write this code in my project & it's works for me, just do above solution then check i am sure it's work.

Comment: This will create two product lists though. Sure, the products are not actually rendered, but it seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's not moving by using XML, Because It's commenting in **module-catalog/templates/product/list.phtml** file.

```
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

Also it's define in module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml **category.products.list** block

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
            <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, So is that no option to show toolbar before both container ?

Yes, I have seen both files already

Comment: I have no more idea about that, But "move" method is not working on this scenario.

Comment: Whilst this adds insight, it does not add any useful information how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try This code Create the custom module.

Add this code in `catalog_category_view.xml`:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="{{Package Name}}\{{Your Module Name}}\Block\Toolbar" before="-" name="product_list_custom_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Now Create New `Toolbar.php` a file at `{{Package Name}}\{{Your Module Name}}\Block\Toolbar` Then past below code in that new file:

```
namespace {{Package Name}}\{{Your Module Name}}\Block;
class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public function getCollection()
    {
        $productList = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('category.products.list');
        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $productList->getAvailableOrders();
        if ($orders) {
            $this->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $productList->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $this->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $productList->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $this->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $productList->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $this->setModes($modes);
        }
        $coo = $productList->getLoadedProductCollection();
        // set collection to productList and apply sort
        $this->setCollection($productList->getLoadedProductCollection());
        return parent::getCollection();
    }
}
```

Now remove default block from the layout of category view.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The toolbar will still simply not render at all. And I do not understand why. There is not even a call to its `toHtml` method.

Comment: The problem is the `$this->setChild()` call in `configureToolbar` of the `ProductList`. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7253#issuecomment-439630823

Answer (score 2):

You can move sidebar before main content area using layout code below :

Step 1 :
create / copy **2columns-left.xml** file in your **Magento_Theme/page_layout/** folder and replace below contents:

Also you can change / add your css classes in container.

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="1column"/>
<referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="column main col-md-10"/>
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="col-sidebar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-2" before="main">
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional testing-123-festing" before="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Module way.**

Create a new module Vendor_Module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Add a plugin to prevent the default toolbar from showing.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="vendor-catalog-productlist" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ProductList" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/ProductList.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class ProductList
{
    /**
     * After dispatch
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject
     * @param string $result
     */
    public function afterGetToolbarHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Add a new block to the category page.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\ListProduct\Toolbar" name="vendor.category.products.list">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="product_list_block_name" xsi:type="string">category.products.list</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/ListProduct/Toolbar.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\ListProduct;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $productList = $this->getLayout()->getBlock(
            $this->getData('product_list_block_name')
        );
        if ($productList) {
            $productList->toHtml();
            return $productList->getChildHtml('toolbar');
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

**2. You can apply the same changes to your theme**

You no need plugin because you can just comment a line where default toolbar rendered.

Comment `$block->getToolbarHtml()` lines in

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Create the same toolbar class and put it in xml layout.

> Vendor\Module\Block\ListProduct\Toolbar

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the old code base of the toolbar and product list relationship. Some of it has already been rectified in Magento 2.2.x, but there are still problems. For instance, no matter where or how you put your toolbar in the layout, the product list block will *always* move the toolbar back as its own child (see [this comment on Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7253#issuecomment-439630823)).

Here is yet another solution which is a combination of Nicholas Miller's and kunj's solution. The advantage over Nicholas Miller's and Chirag Patel's solution is, that the product collection will not be loaded twice.

*Vendor/Module/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php*

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    public const DEFAULT_PRODUCTLIST_BLOCKNAME = 'category.products.list';

    protected function getProductListBlock()
    {
        $blockName = $this->getProductListBlockName();

        if ($blockName) {
            return $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        }

        return $this->getLayout()->getBlock(self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTLIST_BLOCKNAME) ?: null;
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        if (!empty(parent::getCollection())) {
            return parent::getCollection();
        }

        $productList = $this->getProductListBlock();

        if (empty($productList)) {
            return parent::getCollection();
        }

        $productList->configureToolbarPublic($this, $productList->getLoadedProductCollection());

        return parent::getCollection();
    }
}
```

*Vendor/Module/Block/Product/ListProduct.php*

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

use Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarFromLayout();

        if (!$toolbar) {
            $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));
            $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        }

        $this->configureToolbarPublic($toolbar, $collection);

        $collection->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function configureToolbarPublic(Toolbar $toolbar, Collection $collection)
    {
        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if ($orders) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $this->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }
        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);
    }
}
```

*etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />

</config>
```

Now you should be able to move the `product_list_toolbar` freely without any problems. e.g.: *catalog_category_view.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="content" before="-" />
    </body>
</page>
```

As an added bonus you can also set a custom product list block name, if you need to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock element="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setProductListBlockName">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">my_product_list_block</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Likewise, the correct toolbar block name should also be set accordingly on the product list's block (if your custom toolbar's name is something other than the default).

#### Update

For this solution to work, you need at least Magento `2.2.6`.

Comment: This is not working in 2.2.5. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My code was tested with `2.2.6`. I am not sure if there are any significant differences between `2.2.5` and `2.2.6` regarding the product list block or toolbar block.

Comment: Are these all the files and code a need for making the extension? I also added a module.xml. I'm not sure if there is anything I'm missing.

Comment: Also for the file Vendor/Module/Block/Product/ProductList.php was it supposed ot be ListProduct.php?

Comment: I only included the relevant files, of course you need more files than that to actually make your extension work within Magento. Like `etc/modules.xml` and the `registration.php` for example.

Comment: And yes, you are right, it was supposed to be `ListProduct.php`,  not `ProductList.php`, thank you :). I'll edit that.

Comment: I fixed all that before adding my first comment. Still not working for me even though this is not the first time I've created an extension.

Comment: Hm... should be working. So is the toolbar simply not rending for you, when you try to `<move>` it in your layout xml?

Comment: When I try to move it to the content block I'm still getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSize() on null in C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list\toolbar.phtml:18

Comment: This might indicate that `Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar::getCollection` is unable to find the product list block.

Comment: You are right it works in 2.2.6. Not sure what the difference is but I'll just update. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I think there have been some significant changes in 2.2.6 regarding the Toolbar and ListProduct block. I have added the minimum Magento version in the original answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add below code in `catalog_category_view.xml` file in your custom theme:-

```
<move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="columns.top" after="-" />
```

Comment: This will not work due to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7253#issuecomment-439630823