# Always Showing Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, category

So I've extended the Layered Navigation to include a few extra option collectables that are always there, regardless of filters applied.  I would like to have the Layered Nav show up on all category pages because of this, even when the category you're in doesn't have any products.  Where should I go about looking to force this?

Alright, as far as I've gotten;

I've used `catagory_catalog_view_type_default.xml` to get the block onto every page.  I was able to confirm that the block is being loaded up via a DD in the constructor.  However, the template simply does not get loaded up, even when I place items outside of the `canShowBlock()` check, which suggests to me there is some kind of check elsewhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225471/magento2-how-to-move-toolbar/226042#answer-226042

Comment: @SaphalJha  What in particular there?