# How to move product_list_toolbar magento 2?

Tags: category, magento2.3.1, toolbar, product-listing

I want to move toolbar above column. I am using this code:

```
<move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="columns.top" before="-" />
```

I am getting the getSize() error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSize() on null in /app/design/frontend/Digital/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml:18`

Comment: Where u Want toolbar please explain or provide your toolbar.phtml code..

Comment: it is default toolbar.phtml, I am using this code in catalog_category_view.xml

Comment: Where U want toolbar ?

Comment: Above product_list and layered_navigation

Comment: Currently, this is showing: https://nimb.ws/Rz62qH .

But I want to show like this: https://nimb.ws/I35VDL

Comment: PleaseCan u Chek This Link  :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225471/magento2-how-to-move-toolbar

Comment: it is for sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Copy catalog_category_view.xml into your Theme

```
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
             <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="custom-category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
             <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="custom-category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list1.phtml">
              <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
            </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Then create product/list1.phtml file into your theme.

```
        <?php
            $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
            $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
        ?>
        <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

final in product/list.phtml remove or comment its.

```
        <?php
        <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
        ?>
```

Comment: Not working! when we apply sorting through bottom toolbar then top toolbar should be updated simultaneously but it does not. While when we apply sorting from top toolbar then bottom toolbar is updating accordingly..what is the issue?